# TV Listing iOS5

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, television

I'm about to begin the development for a tv listing on iPad. I'd like to have a tv listing iTV alike but I don't seem to find where to begin or if I should use tables or scrollviews with nested views. I think the horizontal behavior is the most challenging here. If someone here could put me in the right direction It'd be awesome.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial could help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

It explains how to layout a UITableView inside a UITableView like the pulse application

Comment: Thanks I was looking around for other solution but I got back to this tutorial and after taking a little bit of time I understood how it works and implemented myself, it's really good.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a sort of grid view component that supports horizontal scrolling.

Here's a comprehensive review of some of the options out there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100380/ios-grid-view-with-support-for-horizontal-scrolling